# Is there a option to run next instance 1 minute after the first instance in php

Tags: php, joomla

I have a independent php script and it need to be run on server which is based on joomla.

where i want the script should run recursively after every min from it's execution.

Where script contain while loop and header function of php

So do suggest any method to achieve this task.

Comment: or Task Scheduler?

Comment: By CRON time interval will be fixed for 1min.
where i want to run the script 1min after its execution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following script to set cron in runtime.

```
<?phps
$output = shell_exec('crontab -l');
file_put_contents('/tmp/crontab.txt', $output.'* * * * * NEW_CRON'.PHP_EOL);
echo exec('crontab /tmp/crontab.txt');
?>
```